# Resize div to fit clicked button size and float over another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that title here is hard to understand. I really need help changing this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yh7m182w/1/). So here is what I am trying to do:

When button is clicked, I want the div (coding) to resize to the size of the button itself and I want the button with div(coding) to float over the div (coding2). (coding2) div should resize to its full width at that time.
When button is clicked again, bring the view back to the way it was initially. Attached you will  find an image of before and after of what I am looking for. All of this I hope to accomplish just using CSS.

```
<div id="coding">
<button id = "content" onclick="dosomething()">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div id = "coding2">
</div>
```

[image: Initial State]
[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch the width of the both `div`s between `0%` to `50%` for the first one and `49%` to `100%` for the second one:

```js
 function dosomething() {
  if($('#coding').width() > 0){
    $('#coding').width('0')
    $('#coding2').width('100%')
  }
  else {
    $('#coding').width('50%')
    $('#coding2').width('49%')
  }
 }
```

```css
#coding {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  overflow:visible;
  background:yellow;
}


#coding2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 49%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  z-index:0;
  background:blue;
}
button {
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coding" class="larger">
<button onclick="dosomething()">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div id = "coding2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` used to be the way to create layouts, but nowadays we have tools like [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) to create awesome layouts with.

The example below use the former, Grid, which enables you to create a layout and place your child elements within that layout. All width and height calculations are done from the parent (`#grid`). All the children (`#coding` and `#coding2`) have to do is say where in the grid they need to go.

With JavaScript, and in this case jQuery, listen to a click on the button. Then toggle a class on the `#grid` element. With that class you can set styles on the children which can make them move around in the grid, and in this case, take the width of the entire parent (`#grid`).

```js
$('#button').on('click', () => {
  $('#grid').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
#grid {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}

#button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#coding {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: blue;
}

#coding2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}

#grid.is-active #coding2 {
 grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid">
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>
  <div id="coding"></div>
  <div id="coding2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 classes, two for each div. The just use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove it on button click.

```js
 function dosomething() {
   $("#coding").toggleClass("clicked unclicked");
   $("#coding2").toggleClass("clicked2 unclicked2");
 }
```

```css
#coding {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#coding2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}


.clicked {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.unclicked {
  width: 50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
  float: left;
}

.clicked2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float: none;
}

.unclicked2{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="coding" class="unclicked">
<button onclick="dosomething()">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div id="coding2" class="unclicked2">
</div>
```